# How/Where does Firefox 12.0 on Mac OS X store uri maps?

Tags: macos, firefox, browser-cache

I have a site that started behaving strangely yesterday in Firefox 12.0.

When clicking on a link `/home/write-journal`, the actual request is sent to a different URI `/join`.

In Safari & Chrome this does not happen the link properly goes to `/home/write-journal`.

How and where does Firefox cache this information?

I am trying to figure out where it started messing up before I clear the cache (which will hopefully fix the problem).

BTW, I am looking at the live server's access log to know which page is being requested.

When clicking on the link, the first line to appear in the server's access log is:

```
10.10.0.55 - - [15/May/2012:10:01:51 -0400] "GET /join HTTP/1.1" 302 1390 "http://example.org/home/profile" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0"
```

When accessing the same page in Chrome the access log is:

```
10.10.0.55 - - [15/May/2012:10:03:21 -0400] "GET /home/write-journal HTTP/1.1" 200 44251 "http://example.org/home" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.168 Safari/535.19"
```

FWIW, I do have an override set in /etc/hosts to point the url to a lan-local server instead of a remote server.

The `/etc/hosts` line:

```
10.10.0.98      example.org
```

#### Update

I looked at the request in Firebug and FF had cached the request due to a 301 redirect yesterday.

The redirect was cached until the year 2106.